# Leave / Put someone somewhere

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference, verbs

We can freely use **"put / leave something somewhere"**, like in:

> - I'm sure I (put / left) the keys right there, but they are not there now!

But I need to know whether they both can be used when it comes to someone rather than something too. For instance in the following example:

> - I **left the kids** at my sister's house so I could go to my doctor's appointment.

can we substitute "put" for "left" without any change in meaning in a natural and idiomatic idiomatic way?

Please let me know about this application.

Comment: Why do you think they have the same meaning? Have you referenced dictionaries or any other sources? What did you find?

Comment: Because AFAIC normally "**putting** something somewhere" and "**leaving** something somewhere" imply the same message. I needed to make sure whether it is applicable to an individual too or not @gotube.

Comment: No, the two are different words. To "leave" something means to not bring something with you when you go somewhere else. "Put" has nothing to do with bringing something nor going somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful: you can "leave" something that you didn't "put" there in the first place. Someone could have put it there before you arrived and you simply never touched it.

Regarding your question, "putting" a person anywhere isn't very natural. "Put" is used when you transfer an object from one place to another, like *putting* your keys on the table or *putting* the food in the fridge.

Rarely would you "put" someone somewhere because you're essentially treating them as if they are an inanimate object and not a human being. I can only think of two exceptions to this:

1. a baby or young child of yours ("***Put** Sarah in her crib.*")
2. talking about a person or group who is or needs to be moved somewhere ("***Put** that family at the larger table.*")